# How to find N grams of a word in Java?

Tags: java, string, algorithm, loops, recursion

For example if the input is "name" and  the minGram is 1 and maxGramSize is 2 output will consist of n,a,m,e,na,am,me. If the minGram=2, maxGram=4 inputWord=name, output = na,am,me,nam,ame,name.

Function signature can be something like this:

```
public List<String> generateNGrams(String input, int minGramSize, int maxGramSize)
```

Initially I tried doing it with for loops, but I was finding it hard to follow the indices. Then I tried solving it using recursion with pen and paper but I'm still struggling with it. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: This sounds like it would be more natural to solve it with for loops rather than recursion. It'll be a lot easier to see where you're going wrong if you post the code you've tried so far though :)

Comment: Doing this to educate yourself or for production? In the latter case have a look at http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_0_3/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ngram/NGramTokenizer.html

Comment: @Drunix To educate myself, not for production. I want to solve it without libraries. Thanks for the link though.

Comment: Then follow Animatinators advice and show your attempts.

Comment: @Animatinator Okay, I have added what I had so far.

Comment: Tip: Depending on what you are trying to do, if you implementing text search: Don't create all n-grams explicitly into a list. Its much better to implement an algorithm that slides a `q`-window over the text calculating some hash over each q-gram and enter those into a statically sized bit-array ("bloom filter"). Since you have to to a exact comparison of candidates anyway, this should lead a much more efficient text-retrieval.

Answer (score 2):

One solution:

```
private static void addNgrams(final int size, final String input, 
    final List<String> list)
{
    final int maxStartIndex = input.length() - size;
    for (int i = 0; i < maxStartIndex; i++)
        list.add(input.stubString(i, i + size));
}

public List<String> generateNGrams(final String input, final int minSize, 
    final int maxSize)
{
    final List<String> ret = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int size = minSize; size <= maxSize; size++)
        addNgrams(size, input, ret);
    return ret;
}
```

Note: lacks basic error checkings (for instance, `maxSize` greater than the size of `input`; `minSize` greater than `maxSize`; others); left as an exercise.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a program that recursively generates nGrams: This code also handles the tail grams.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

  public class NGrams {

  ArrayList<String> nGrams = new ArrayList<String>();

  public void generateNGrams(String str, int n) {

    if (str.length() == n ) {
        int counter = 0;
        while (counter < n) {
          nGrams.add(str.substring(counter));
          counter++;
        }
        return;
    }

    int counter = 0;
    String gram = "";
    while (counter < n) {
        gram += str.charAt(counter);
        counter++;
    }
    nGrams.add(gram);
    generateNGrams(str.substring(1), n);
  }

  public void printNGrams() {
    for (String str : nGrams) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    NGrams ng = new NGrams();
    ng.generateNGrams("hello world", 3);
    ng.printNGrams();

  }

}
```

Output:

```
hel
ell
llo
lo 
o w
 wo
wor
orl
rld
ld
d
```